# [android]How to implement Jess Ander's TwoWayGridView?

Tags: android, gridview, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to dynamically add image buttons on the click of a button. When the number of image button exceeds the screen width, I should be able to horizontally scroll. I tried to implement [Jess-Ander's TwoWayGridView](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview) but with no success. I am a beginner. So please bear with me if the mistake is too elementary.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Button" />

<com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#E8E8E8"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"
app:columnWidth="80dp"
app:rowHeight="80dp"
app:numColumns="auto_fit"
app:numRows="2"
app:verticalSpacing="16dp"
app:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
app:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
app:scrollDirectionPortrait="vertical"
app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
app:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the code:

```
package com.example.dynamic;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout linearLayout1;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);



}

public void onClick(View v){

    ImageView image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    linearLayout1.addView(image);        

}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having problems getting the spacing correct using the values in xml, you could try looking at the following tutorial:

http://spragucm.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/android-horizontal-and-vertical-gridview-tutorial/

I specifically wrote it because the two-way-gridview items wouldn't space evenly and they wouldn't fill the row/column. The example code in my tutorial lets you set column and row number and everything else is done for you so that the child fills a row/column with some padding between items.

The example code demonstrates how to use the two-way-gridview in either orientation.

As for setting the onClickListener...you will need to setOnItemClickListener() on the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I have been messing around to implement Two-way gridview, but finally implemented it my way:

```
<ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/mainscrolView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >


                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/rclv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >


                        <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/table"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:stretchColumns="*"
                            >

                        </TableLayout>

                </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

I add the children of TableLayout programmatically. Like:

```
TableLayout tv =  findViewById(R.id.table);
 tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();

 TableRow tr = new TableRow(AndroidDatabaseManager.this);

 tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 TextView b3 = new TextView(AndroidDatabaseManager.this);
b3.setText("Child");
tr.addView(b3);

 tv.addView(tr);

                final View vline = new View(AndroidDatabaseManager.this);
                vline.setLayoutParams(new
                        TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,2));
                vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                tv.addView(vline);
```